# Return VariableTable From Stored Procedure to another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

This is not a question I just wanted to share an idea that may help developers

This example simuate how can I return variable table from procedure to another procedure

Example procedure

```
Create Proc [dbo].[ReturnVariableTable] (
    @_PersonID uniqueidentifier, @_fromdate date , @_Todate date 
    @obj_cursor cursor varying output
) as
Begin Try
    Begin Tran
DECLARE @PersonSalaryOverYear Table(_Salary Float  ,PersonID uniqueidentifier ,Month Int )
declare @tempdate = @_fromdate 
while ( @tempdate <= @_Todate )
BEGIN

declare @_Salary FLOAT = (select Salary from Person where ID = @_PersonID AND Month(@tempdate) = MonthNumber   ) 
insert into @PersonSalaryOverYear values(@_Salary, @_PersonID,Month(@tempdate) )
select  @tempdate = DATEADD(Month,1,@tempdate)

END 


    Set @obj_cursor = cursor forward_only static for
        select @_Salary as Salary, @_PersonID as PersonID ,Month(@tempdate) as Month 

    Open @obj_cursor

    Commit
End Try
```

### How to call

```
Declare @cur Cursor
Declare @_Salary Float
Declare @_PersonID uniqueidentifier 
Declare @Month int
Exec ReturnMultipleData 
    @_PersonID = '2121ad51-fa84-4da4-a9e6-c22e259d549e',@_fromdate='10-01-2013' ,       @_Todate='10-31-2013'
    @obj_cursor = @cur OUTPUT 

Fetch Next From @cur into @_Salary,  @_PersonID,@Month
While @@fetch_status = 0
Begin
   print @_Salary
   print @_PersonID
   print @Month

   Fetch Next From cur into  @_Salary,  @_PersonID,@Month
End
Close @cur
Deallocate @cur
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use two output parameters to do this? And why would you store a salary as a float instead of a decimal type?

Comment: This is only example to explain my idea

Comment: I use this way in the first to return variable table not only one or two parameters

Comment: If you can think of a way to ask a question, and then provide this as the answer, then you can do that.  But this is not a question as it is right now.  See here http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I have less than 15 reputation

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're going to have multiple rows in the cursor, this is more straightforward:

```
Create Proc dbo.ReturnMultipleData 
    @PersonID uniqueidentifier,
    @Salary decimal(10, 2) out,
    @Att uniqueidentifier out
As

Select
    @Salary = p.Salary,
    @Att = a.AttendanceID
From
    Person p
        Left Outer Join
    VPerson_AttendanceNumber a
        On p.ID = a.PersonID
Where
    p.ID = @PersonID
```

Comment: But how you will do if you want to return table not only variable

Comment: @user2516356 Use a table valued function? How would your version work in this case?

Comment: I edit the Post to return Variable Table check it and if you have any question I will reply I try this way and it is very useful and help me I some work